# Is it possible to make a multiplatform mobile app only using Windows?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, flutter, multiplatform

With my team from the university, we are carrying out the final degree project. We need to create a multiplatform mobile application, each of us has Windows computers.

We are thinking of using react or flutter, if you know any other technology that we can use, we are open to ideas.

The question is the following, to deploy the application in IOS, is it necessary to have a MAC computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to build, deploy and publish to Apple you will need a Mac and an Iphone, together with an developer account.

Answer (score 2):

If your computer has more then 8GB of RAM you can install a macOS in VM Ware or Virtual Box

Comment: Is there a working image of macOS? I found a few post and videos but the image of MacOS never work.

Comment: Yes i also have an macOS BigSur on my widows 10 PC

Comment: I recommend you to watch this video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y936EQCVZSQ

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend React Native. The app you build on android will run very similarly on ios. There are certain differences, but most can be planned around.

Comment: Flutter builds just like React Native, for both plataforms similarly. The problem is not the build, but the deploy and publishment

Comment: I admittedly don't know much about Flutter. I'd just assume that React Native would be more tolerant to both platforms since it's developed by a third party.

Comment: @GuilhermeZamberlamPomini Which do you think is easier?

Comment: @AgustinRodriguez Flutter by far, RN is good but Flutter is the future. In my company we have legacy apps in RN that only gives us headache, every new app is being made in Flutter.